# how does token validation works on token based authantication systems

Tags: authentication, oauth, token

When token based authantication is compared to traditional server authantication, it is said that: traditional method keeps login info in memory on server side, but in token based authantication server keeps nothing. Information about logged in user is stored in token itself.

However, I didn't get one point here. If server doesn't store anything, how does server validate the token? I think it should store the secret key to decrypt the token and then validate.

If so, where is it stored? If not what poin did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server issuing the token, [digitally signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the token with a private key.

The service consuming the token only needs the public key to validate the token. It can download the public key from the issuing server on startup or first use. After that, it does not need to communicate with the issuing server to validate tokens. If the signature is valid, the service trusts the contents of the token.

Answer (score 1):

For example, look at the "[jwt](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)", it uses "ssh" keys

Comment: In ssh, don't we need a key to encrypt and decrypt the data? If we need a key, server should keep this key somewhere. Is it stored in memory or database?

Comment: You can use just one secret key for all tokens, and keep it in memory. All other user-specific data locates in tokens.